# How to pass a id value from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass a id value from view to controller but i have 2 options

1. using anchor tag with uri segment 
   2.with hidden field form

I  think both cant be used , if possible please guide me

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($array['value']);$i++) { ?>
<?php $id= $array['value'][$i]['arrayIndex']; ?>
      echo form_open('controller/array_storage/'.$id)
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'foo'.$i ?>" value="<?php  echo $array['value'][$i]['foo']?>" /> 
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'boo'.$i?>" value="<?php  echo $array['value'][$i]['boo']?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'bar'.$i?>" value="<?php  echo $array['value'][$i]['bar']?>" />
 <input type="submit">
   <? } ?>
```

here is my controller

```
  <?php 
   function array_storage($id) 

  {
 $foo = $this->input->post('foo'.$id);
 $boo =   $this->input->post('boo'.$id);
 $bar =  $this->input->post('bar'.$id);
 }
 ?>
```

here is my array

```
    array(4) { ["aa"]=> int(12) ["b"]=> string(4) "2222" ["c"]=> string(3) "232" ["array"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(7) { ["test"]=> string(5) "23132" ["aaa"]=> int(131) ["bbb"]=> string(4) "sgsg" ["ccc"]=> string(6) "qweqrq" ["ddd"]=> NULL ["eee"]=> int(0) ["value"]=> array(4) { ["foo"]=> int(46546) ["boo"]=> string(6) "231231" ["bar"]=> string(4) "test" ["TDS"]=> string(3) "0.0" } } [1]=> array(7) { ["test"]=> string(5) "23132" ["aaa"]=> int(131) ["bbb"]=> string(4) "sgsg" ["ccc"]=> string(6) "qweqrq" ["ddd"]=> NULL ["eee"]=> int(0) ["value"]=> array(4) { ["foo"]=> int(46546) ["boo"]=> string(6) "231231" ["bar"]=> string(4) "test" ["TDS"]=> string(3) "0.0" } } [2]=> array(7) { ["test"]=> string(5) "23132" ["aaa"]=> int(131) ["bbb"]=> string(4) "sgsg" ["ccc"]=> string(6) "qweqrq" ["ddd"]=> NULL ["eee"]=> int(0) ["value"]=> array(4) { ["foo"]=> int(46546) ["boo"]=> string(6) "231231" ["bar"]=> string(4) "test" ["TDS"]=> string(3) "0.0" } } [3]=> array(7) { ["test"]=> string(5) "23132" ["aaa"]=> int(131) ["bbb"]=> string(4) "sgsg" ["ccc"]=> string(6) "qweqrq" ["ddd"]=> NULL ["eee"]=> int(0) ["value"]=> array(4) { ["foo"]=> int(46546) ["boo"]=> string(6) "231231" ["bar"]=> string(4) "test" ["TDS"]=> string(3) "0.0" } } } }
```

Help me to fix the issue

convreted json to view easily

```
{
  "aa": 12,
  "b": "2222",
  "c": "232",
  "array": [
    {
      "arrayIndex": "1",
      "aaa": 131,
      "bbb": "sgsg",
      "ccc": "qweqrq",
      "ddd": null,
      "eee": 0,
      "value": {
        "foo": 46546,
        "boo": "231231",
        "bar": "test",
        "TDS": "0.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "arrayIndex": "2",
      "aaa": 131,
      "bbb": "sgsg",
      "ccc": "qweqrq",
      "ddd": null,
      "eee": 0,
      "value": {
        "foo": 46546,
        "boo": "231231",
        "bar": "test",
        "TDS": "0.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "arrayIndex": "3",
      "aaa": 131,
      "bbb": "sgsg",
      "ccc": "qweqrq",
      "ddd": null,
      "eee": 0,
      "value": {
        "foo": 46546,
        "boo": "231231",
        "bar": "test",
        "TDS": "0.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "arrayIndex": "4",
      "aaa": 131,
      "bbb": "sgsg",
      "ccc": "qweqrq",
      "ddd": null,
      "eee": 0,
      "value": {
        "foo": 46546,
        "boo": "231231",
        "bar": "test",
        "TDS": "0.0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Post your complete array if possible...

Comment: Here is how my sample array look like

Comment: Seems you forgot to put `$id` in form action `<?php echo form_open("controller/array_storage/$id"); ?>`. (you have misspelled **controller** word here).

Comment: i have tried too but $id returns value 1 always

Comment: echo form_open('controller/array_storage/'.$id)

Comment: @mvd What is your id in this array ??

Comment: i have created a look a like array so i have missed it consider test as id value

Comment: not yet.................

Comment: is the approach correct??

Comment: why is that you can't send using hidden form element??Please elaborate

Comment: @sagar Is above approach is correct, when  i click submit null value is returned in controller

Comment: is you issue not getting $id value in controller or it is something else??

Comment: The selected forms value is not getting in controller

Comment: Please check the below mentioned code .I guess that will give you the result.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code in my local please see at it if this is similar to your problem then find and replace accordingly.I have tested this code and it works fine.

```
//This is your view

<?php for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) { ?>
<?php $id= '1'; 
      echo form_open('index.php/welcome/array_storage/'.$id)?>
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'foo'.$i ?>" value="<?php  echo "2"?> /> 
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'boo'.$i?>" value="<?php  echo "23"?> />
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'bar'.$i?>" value="23" />
 <input type="submit">

   <?php } ?>

//this is controller function

    function array_storage($id) 
 {
    echo $id;
     echo $this->input->post('foo'.$id);
      echo $this->input->post('boo'.$id);
 }
```

Comment: how to get foo value in controller

Comment: @mvd if this solved your issue please upvote the answer...else inform me

Comment: only null value is returning while i submit the form

Comment: did you send the $id value as either 0,1,2??

Comment: better debug by checking the value as  print_r($this->input->post()) and check if any value is set.Next thing you do is copy the code provided by me and check for that piecce of code if it works.

Answer (score 0):

why not try this

```
<?php $total_count = count($array['value']); 
     for($i=0;$i<total_count ;$i++) { ?>
       <?php $id= $array['value'][$i]['arrayIndex']; ?>
       // @note the name attribute of the form is set
       echo form_open('controller/array_storage/'.$id , "name='form-storage-$id'")

 <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php  echo $array['value'][$i]['boo']?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="bar" value="<?php  echo $array['value'][$i]['bar']?>" />
```

Then controller

```
function array_storage($id = '') 
{
   $array = get_the_array();

   if( array_key_exists( $id , $array )
   {

      $foo = $this->input->post('foo');
      $boo =   $this->input->post('boo');
      $bar =  $this->input->post('bar');

    else
    {
        // error : invalid index 
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the use of name attribute

Comment: Because multiple form exists with input element that has same name attribute.

Comment: get_the_array(); how to get that

Comment: get_the_array(); should be replaced with your function that returns data saved in your storage. i just used that as get_the_array() demostration